# SharePoint Name displays as i:0#domain\username when converting People Picker to string

Tags: string, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow, peoplepicker

I have a workflow that copies a string version of a People Picker column to another column

Name = People Picker Column
NameString = copy of people picker column as a string

Workflow: 
Set NameString to Current Item:Name

It worked fine for a couple of months but all of the sudden it started setting some NamesStrings to i:0#domain\username. I can't find any pattern for why it does some and not others and why it is doing it in the first place. Has anyone else had this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I was having issues with SharePoint Designer. When I opened designer the next day I was unable to edit any of the workflows. I had to uninstall and then reinstall designer. When I did that I saw that workflow was set up to return the NameString as a string instead of as display name. When I updated that everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, we can use the **Extract Substring from Index of String** action to remove the i:0#.w| from the user name.

The workflow settings as below:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for responding. The issue is it's only putting the i:0#.domain in front of some of the usernames; some are showing up exactly as they should. So if I use the above workflow it will cut off the names that are showing up correctly.